# Заблудилась в тире... Как быть с ними в моих трёх предложениях?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

> Входной фасад Санта-Мария-Маджоре – тот самый случай. Поэтому здесь
>   нужно выхватить лучший – диагональный вид от угла, перспективу. И
>   сквозь колоннаду крыльца – сразу туда, внутрь, в торжественную
>   роскошь.

Перед *тот* и *сразу* - я нарисовала.

*Поэтому здесь нужно выхватить лучший – диагональный вид от угла, перспективу,* - всё авторское, нетронутое; что с этим делать?

Добавить ещё одно тире - после "диагональный"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тире перед *тот* и *сразу* возражений не вызывают. А вот фраза про вид - проблематичная. Мой вариант:

Поэтому здесь нужно выхватить лучший вид — диагональный от угла, перспективу.

Answer (score 2):

**Можно оставить все тире,** они нужны в каждом предложении:

Входной фасад Санта-Мария-Маджоре – тот самый случай. Поэтому здесь нужно выхватить лучший (вид) – диагональный вид от угла, перспективу. И сквозь колоннаду крыльца – сразу туда, внутрь, в торжественную роскошь.

Во втором предложении конструкция нестандартная, но два тире туда не подойдут. А одно тире обозначает паузу на месте пропущенного существительного.